# Should I use Reverse DNS (rDNS) with or without "www."?

Tags: dns

If I set up a rDNS entry for my server, should I enter just the hostname or should I include `www.`?

I assume that the A-Record for `example.com` and `www.example.com` point to the same server, of course. The site is running on `www.example.com`, if that matters.

I am asking because I have been told different stuff by different support members of my hosting provider. I am sorry that I can not give you a link to a resource with any of these opinions, as I am not even sure what to search for.

An answer from personal experience would be great, but I would prefer if someone here knows of an "official" document that states this.

Comment: Reverse DNS requires that you have a dedicated IP address. This would be a PTR record. If you are on a shared server, you would/should not set-up a PTR record. As well, use a CNAME record to point www.example.com to example.com. Example.com would have an A record and not sub-domains such as www.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain name returned from the reverse DNS lookup of the IP address should itself have an `A` record in its DNS record that points back to the IP address (in order to be "forward-confirmed").

So, in the case of a `www` subdomain, which is *usually* just a `CNAME` record pointing to the main domain, you should probably specify the bare domain. eg. `example.com`.

Comment: BTW- The OP should not be setting up a PTR record on a shared host.

Comment: @closetnoc thanks, I was talking about a server with an own IP

Comment: @simonthesorcerer I was not sure. We get people with varying levels of understanding here. I was just making sure since this seemed important. Cheers!!